# GoogleSQL query first range of records and perform average

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Using GoogleSQL I want to extract just the **first 24 records** of each record_id, based on time period. After that perform an average over that range (1-24), and also calculate the growth rate period over period.
Query  works fine but looking for optimization.

```
record_id, period, downloads
123, 2004-01-02, 100
123, 2004-01-09, 200
345, 2004-01-09, 180
123, 2004-01-16, 110
345, 2004-01-16, 200
345, 2004-01-23, 500
123, 2004-01-23, 100
```

SQL Query:

```
    SELECT
      id,
      period,
      record_id,
      downloads,
      AVG(downloads) OVER (PARTITION BY record_id) AS avg_downloads,
      100 * (downloads - growth) / growth AS growth_rate_percent, -- (Present - Past) / Past
      AVG(growth_rate_percent) OVER (PARTITION BY record_id) AS avg_growth_rate_percent
    FROM 
      (SELECT
        record_id,
        period,
        downloads AS downloads,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY record_id ORDER BY period) AS id,        -- Enumerate Rows.
        LAG(downloads) OVER (PARTITION BY record_id ORDER BY period) AS growth,  -- Previous Record.      
        AVG(downloads) OVER (PARTITION BY record_id) AS avg_all_downloads,     -- Average downloads.
       FROM
        my_table)
  WHERE id <= 24;
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` (or equivalent? What makes you think that your query needs further optimisation?